# Regex number followed by date with no space

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I have the following rows:

```
fact prof 45883
factura PROF 46186
FACT.PROF:45126
FACT.PROF.NR.46069
FACTURA PROF. 46296
factura prof.46673
FAC PROFORMA PROF 46876
FACT 44046
FACT 46529
fact proforma nr 46229
FCT PROF:40365
PROF 44283
fact prof 46646
FACT PROF: 45666
fact PROF:45560
Factura proforma : 46059
FCT PROF 45108
fact. proforma nr.46180
FACTURA PROFORMA NR 43864 SI FACTURA PROFORMA NR 43865
PROF 46471
prof nr 42840
PROF. NR.45830
FAC. PROFORMA NR. 46373
fact prof 38518
f prof 45983
factura proforma 46753
factura  prof 46326
f prof 46645
f prof 43723
fact prof.nr 46227
factura proforma 41292
prof 45602
F.45026
FAC. PROFORMA: 43017
FACT 43198
FACT PROF 46284
fact proforma nr 45984
fact prof 46656
fact. nr. 45224
fact PROF:46282
prof 45826
PROFORMA 42801
fact prof 45579
FF 46105
FACTURA PROF 45237
factura proforma 43335
fact nr 43709
FACTURA PROF:46962
Seria PRO nr. 43712
SERIA PRO NR : 43099 
PROF 45515
Factura PROF : 45722
PROFORMA Seria PRO nr. 43051
PROF46215
PROF 45131
PROF460798wheels
proforma 43736
proforma 43642 si 38987
Factura 46690
Fproforma 416477
PROF   45608
factura numar 42995
PROF :43679
PROF:46801
Prof45066
PROF: 45613
Factura 45369
prof 46791
PROF 45198
prof 39970
Prof. 46039
Seria PROF NR 45273
fact. proforma 46446
PROF 46911
prof 45044
PROF: 45674
Proforma 46241
PROF: 43943
prof 43769
prof46611
PROFORMA NR 46635
prof. nr. 45597
PROF42088
FACTURA 44235
PROF 46024 SI 46156
proforma 46219
PROFORMA nr. 4712619.05.2015
Proforma 46333 
PROF  44961
PROF 43941
Prof:45303
prof44895
FACTURA 45199
proforma 46263/12.05.15 
PRPROF:46717
```

I need to extract the numbers from the respective strings. I have created a Reg-ex that covers almost all the cases but I have 2 cases that I cannot cover:

1. The first one is PROF460798wheels where the number is concatenated with the name of the firm ( 8wheels )
2. And the second one is PROFORMA nr. 4712619.05.2015 where the number is concatenated with the date.

Is there any way either to exclude this rows or to get the correct numbers ?

This is my regex until now:

```
(?:prof|proforma|F|fact|PRO|factura)\s?\.?\s?(?:nr|numar)?\.?\s?:?\s?(\d+(?!\d\d\.\d{2}\.\d{4}))\s?(?:si)?\s?(\d+)?
```

Some full text examples:

```
Decontare -Platitor: COLCERIU LAURA-ELENA; RO20OTPV112004321192RO01-Beneficiar: SC DUMMY SRL; RO96RNCB0040124547320001; CODFISC 16296240-Detalii: /ROC/Fproforma 416477 din 14.05.15//RFB/16
Decontare -Platitor: Aliman Samuel-lucian; RO61INGB2220999904092615-Beneficiar: DUMMY; RO96RNCB4090124247370001-Detalii: /ROC/PROF:46634/RFB/NONE.
Decontare -Platitor: VLAD CAMBURU; RO61INGB2220999904092615-Beneficiar: DUMMY; RO61INGB2220999904092615-Detalii: /ROC/Factura PROF:43751vlad camburu//RFB/1
Decontare -Platitor: CARP COSMIN; RO20OTPV112004321192RO01; CODFISC NA-Beneficiar: DUMMY; RO20OTPV112004323192RO01; CODFISC NA-Detalii: /ROC/PROF:46583                         Abonament servicii sportive dummy  Partener (65676301) 04/05   03/08
```

Comment: It might be cleaner to sanitize the edge case lines in a first pass, rather than try to construct a regex that matches such mangled input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only thing that you need is the numbers you can use the following Reg-ex:

`/\d+\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+\.\d+|\d+/g`

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/bA6vN4/1

**EDIT**

So apparently you only need the first 5 digits of the number instead of the whole string:

`/\d{5}/g`

https://regex101.com/r/bA6vN4/2

**EDIT**

This one should do it, It removes the date from the number when they are beside each other and takes in consideration your special `8wheels` case:

```
/(?:proforma|PROFORMA|Proforma|factura|FACTURA|Factura|nr|NR|numar|NUMAR|prof|Prof|PROF|fact|FACT|fac|FAC|FCT|si|SI|F)(?:\s?|\.?|:?)*(\d+(?=8wheels|(?:(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})))|\d+)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/fJ3sN6/4

Comment: The string are bigger and contain other numbers. That's why a need the identifiers, and your solution isn't solving my 2 problems.

Comment: since the digits seem to be always five, and they always start from the left, it looks like the solution is good if postprocessed with a substr()

Comment: Could you give the full String since we cannot guess that what you posted isn't the full text...

Comment: Yes for the moment the numbers are have 5 digits but it will increse to 6-7 numbers, and some strings have 2 sets of numbers.

Comment: @neko How can you hope to extract a variable number of digits from a string that may be immediately followed by more digits?  If both 5 and 6 digits is possible, `PROF460798wheels` could very well be `46079` or `460798`.

Comment: @dimo414 I want to extract the number without the company name ( 8wheels ). From the example (PROF460798wheels) i need just the number 46079.

Comment: @neko Do you have a complete list of company names? It would be easier to pre-process those names out first, and replace with a consistent delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:prof|proforma|F|fact|PRO|factura)\s*\.?\s*(?:nr|numar)?\.?\s?:?\s?(\d+(?=(?:\d\d\.\d{2}\.\d{4})|\s*$|[a-z]+))
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nM7nT5/8

Comment: This expression does not cover the cases: proforma 43642 si 38987, proforma 46263/12.05.15 and the PROF460798wheels

Comment: proforma 43642 si 38987, proforma 46263/12.05.15 and the PROF460798wheels

Comment: The PROF460798wheels should return just 46079 without 8wheels, now it returns 460798. And there is another problem that in the string proforma 43642 si 38987 there are 2 numbers.

Comment: @neko when there are `2` then what should be the output

Comment: Should return both numbers